# a quick way to generate a massive matrix of random data

Tags: data-generation

Hi I want to generate a matrix of random data, say row*col = 30000*500000. I tried using VBA in Excel, way to slow; 64 bit R got frozen even I used bigmemory package on my 8G memory box. In order to get it done as fast as possible, should I use C? Is parallel programming in Java 8 helpful on this issue? Anyone has had experience with this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each of your random numbers takes four bytes, you need a total of 60000000000 bytes, that is 60e9 bytes or 55 GiB.  It is no wonder that you cannot hold them all at once in memory on an 8 GiB computer.

If you really need that many random numbers (for what purpose?) your only chance is to write them to a large file, then use them via file acess.  Alternatively, just generate them on the fly when needed; what is better depends on your particular application.

If you also need good quality, I would suggest using a compiler / a library with a good built-in random number gernerator.

Here is a short Fortran example program of how a program to write such a file could look like.  Feel free to adapt to the language of your choice.

```
program random
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: nx = 30000, ny=500000
  real, dimension(ny) :: r  ! A real array of length ny, i.e. 500000
  integer :: i

  open(20,file="random.dat",form="unformatted",access="stream")  ! Byte stream access
  do i=1,nx  ! Do this nx times
     call random_number(r)  ! Fill up the array with pseudorandom numbers
     write (20) r  ! Write it to the file
  end do
  close(20)
end program random
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely makes sense to me.